# How to do a Generic Merge Sort with the Java Interface Comparator?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, mergesort

I'm trying to merge sort lists but get ArrayOutOfBoundsError and don't manage to fix it.

This is for generic Lists using the Comparator interface. For now I'm running test with Integer.

This is my merge sort class:

```
public class ListMS<T> {
    private List<T> wholeList;
    private Comparator<T> comparator;

    public ListMS(List<T> list, Comparator<T> C){
        wholeList=new ArrayList<>();
        wholeList.addAll(list);
        comparator=C;
        mergeSort(wholeList, comparator);

    }

    public static <T> void merge(List<T> L1, List<T> L2,List<T> L, Comparator<T> C){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while(i+j<L.size()){
            if(j==L2.size() || (i<L.size() && C.compare(L1.get(i),L2.get(j))<0)){
                L.set(i+j,L1.get(i++));
            }
            else{
                L.set(i+j,L2.get(j++));
            }
        }
    }

    public static <T> void mergeSort(List<T> L, Comparator<T> C){
        int size=L.size();
        if(size<2){
            return;
        }
        int half=size/2;
        List<T> L1=L.subList(0,half);
        List<T> L2=L.subList(half,size);

        mergeSort(L1,C);
        mergeSort(L1,C);

        merge(L1,L2,L,C);
    }

    public List<T> getWholeList(){
        return wholeList;
    }
}
```

What I'm testing it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparator<Integer> C=new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        };

        List<Integer> list1K=generateList(1000);
        ListMS<Integer> list1KMerged=new ListMS<>(list1K, C);

        printList(list1K);
        printList(list1KMerged.getWholeList());


    }


    public static List<Integer> generateList(int size){
        List<Integer> listNumber=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            int min=0;
            int max=size-1;
            int num=(int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
            listNumber.add(num);
        }
        return listNumber;
    }

    public static void printList(List<Integer> L){
        for(int i=0;i<L.size();i++){
            System.out.print(L.get(i));
        }
    }
```

But I get multiple ArrayOutOfBounds:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   1, Size: 1    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$SubList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1225)   at
>   java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1042)  at
>   ListMS.merge(ListMS.java:19)  at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:40)     at
>   ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)  at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)
>     at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)     at
>   ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)  at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)
>     at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)     at
>   ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)  at ListMS.mergeSort(ListMS.java:37)
>     at ListMS.(ListMS.java:11)    at
>   TestListMS.main(TestListMS.java:16)

Comment: Which one is line 16?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat this line : ListMS<Integer> list1KMerged=new ListMS<>(list1K, C);

Comment: Your merge method is wrong. You can't assume that `i` and `j` are valid indices of `L1` and `L2` as long as `i+j<L.size()`. You have to check whether `i` reached `L1.size()` or `j` reached `L2.size()`.

Comment: @Eran Switching my while to : while(i<L1.size() && j<L2.size()), you mean ? Or a bit further in my conditions ?

Comment: @EmmaVandeWouwer yes, but in addition, after the loop you'll have to add any remaining elements of L1 or L2 to the end of L.

Comment: @Eran Okay thank you ! Doing this I don't have the index error anymore but the list isn't sorted at all ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there is an error in your loop counters in merge() methid at this line:

```
if(j == L2.size() || (i < L.size() && C.compare(L1.get(i), L2.get(j)) < 0))
```

Modify the merge function as so, it will work:

```
public static <T> void merge(List<T> L1, List<T> L2,List<T> L, Comparator<T> C){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        while(i < L1.size() && j < L2.size()) {
            if(C.compare(L1.get(i), L2.get(j)) < 0) {
                L.set(k++, L1.get(i++));
            }else {
                L.set(k++, L2.get(j++));
            }   
        }
        while(i < L1.size()) {
            L.set(k++, L1.get(i++));
        }
        while(j < L2.size()) {
            L.set(k++, L2.get(j++));
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

There are multiple errors in mergeSort function as well. Change it as so:

```
public static <T> void mergeSort(List<T> L, Comparator<T> C){
    int size=L.size();
    if(size<2){
        return;
    }
    int half=size/2;
    List<T> L1=new ArrayList<T>(L.subList(0,half));
    List<T> L2=new ArrayList<T>(L.subList(half,size));

    mergeSort(L1,C);
    mergeSort(L2,C);

    merge(L1,L2,L,C);
    printList(L);
}
```

L1 and L2 were not new array-list in old code. They were just two pointers pointing to same memory locations as in the List L. So modifying L in merge function also modified L1 and L2. In order to solve this, you need to create two new subarrays with separate memory allocations.

Also you were calling `mergeSort(L1,C);` twice instead of calling it on L1 and L2 each.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, the output I get is wrong. The first half is the same repeating number and the second half is in the same order as the original list

Comment: Update the answer. There were errors in your mergesort function as well.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much

Comment: While *in-place merge-sort* is *hard*, there is overhead, but no need to reallocate with every recursive call. In a non-concurrent implementation, you can get by using *one* buffer half the size of `L`. Using an array for "the other buffer" would open an interesting can of worms. For speed, instantiating an `ArrayList` to replace `L` but for the destination of the final merge when `L` doesn't implement `RandomAccess` looks an option to evaluate. (Part of the performance problems to be expected could be sidestepped using `Iterator`s.)

Comment: (I may have been thinking *all purpose* where the question reads *generic*.)